# Loading the model from the library jar file in java

Tags: java

I am trying out a java sample wherein I am trying to load the model class residing in a java library in my project build path. I am not able to. How can I do that?

```
Code

    String model = getModelDir () + "\\english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.see.gz":
```

How can I have the getModelDir () pointing to the included Java library
?